# Answer to an integral is wrong

Tags: integration

I have an integral question, to which I found the same answer at Mathway and Integral but it is labeled wrong by someone:

Question: find $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac{9x^2}{4}}}dx.$$
Answer: $$\frac{2}{3}\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + C.$$

Is the answer really wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE where posts can [use mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).   You should be clearer about what you want to learn.  There are ways to check if integrals are correct, so you know for yourself how to tell.

Comment: Differentiate your answer. If it gives $\frac1{\sqrt{9-9x^2/4}}$, then it is correct

Comment: Confirmed: the answer is correct. Thank Gary for editing, and other comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is definitely right!

Let $x=2 \sin \theta$, then $d x=2 \cos \theta d \theta$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I: &=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac{9x^{2}}{4}}} d x \\
&=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-9 \sin ^{2} \theta}} \cdot 2 \cos \theta d \theta \\
&=\frac{2}{3} \int 1 d \theta \\
&=\frac{2}{3} \theta+C \\
&=\frac{2}{3} \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Nice work! Thanks.